# Replacement of NSURLRequest in WKWebkit

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

When migrating from `UIWebview` to `WKWebview` I assign the `webView` request to `NSURL`,

```
NSURL *myURL = [[webView request] URL];
```

as `request` would be the NSURLRequest, I couldn't see the right one replacing for `WKWebview` and that shows the error,

```
No visible @interface for 'WKWebView` declares the selector 'request'
```

using what I need to replace the `request` in `WKWebView`?

Comment: `WKWebView` has a `URL` property

Comment: Agreed but I don't see this `@property (nullable, nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSURLRequest *request;` in `WKWebview` which is available in `UIWebView.h`

Comment: I understand that.  You don't need the `request` property because `WKWebView` has the `URL` property to get the url directly.